# How can I get the values with jQuery from a input loaded dynamically?

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get the value from a input form, the problem is that I create this input form with jQuery and Ajax so if I check what is the value of that input, it is empty.

The Html that I load dynamically:

```
           <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Desde</label>
                        <input type="time" class="form-control" id="hola" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Desde">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Hasta</label>
                        <input type="time" class="form-control" id="until" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Hasta">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <button type="button" data-id="'.$i.'" class="btn btn-primary search_turn">Buscar</button>
                <hr>
                <h4>Turnos Disponibles</h4>
                <div id="table" class="table-responsive">
                    <table style="width: 100%;" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>Lu</th>
                                <th>Ma</th>
                                <th>Mi</th>
                                <th>Ju</th>
                                <th>Vi</th>
                                <th>Sa</th>
                                <th>Do</th>
                                <th>Horas</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody class="turns">

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="hidden" id="year" value="">
                <input type="hidden" id="month" value="">
                <input type="hidden" id="id_week" value="'.$i.'">
                <input type="hidden" id="id_branch_office" name="id_branch_office" value="'.$id_branch_office.'">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Continuar</button>
            </div>"'
```

This html above I added to this modal dinamically:

```
<!-- Modal -->
                                    <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-xl" id="myModal"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Seleccionar Turno - Semana</h5>
                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-body">

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

When I click in the button Buscar from the first HTML the input since must take the value that I put but it is empty.

My Ajax code:

```
$( 'body' ).on( "click", '.search_turn', function() {
        var $('#edit-auction-modal ').find('input#input-id')

        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');;

        var since = $('#since').val();
        var until = $('#until').val();
        var id_week = $('#id_week').val();
        var id_branch_office = $('#id_branch_office').val();

        if(since != '' && until != '')
        {
            alert(5);
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:"{{ url('/turn/search') }}",
                data: {
                        _token: "{{csrf_token()}}", since: since, until: until, id_branch_office: id_branch_office, id_week: id_week
                },
                success:function(result)
                {
                    $(".turns").html('');
                    $(".turns").html(result);
                }
            });  
        }
    });
```

If I check since variable is empty, why?

Comment: Can you show the code that adds the form to modal? My guess is that you are ending with multiple inputs with same IDs and that's messing the values you get in your onclick function.

Comment: @MichalHynčica is the first one

Comment: Actually, you have no input with id="since" in your html, thats why $('#since').val() is empty.